# switch case statements and run method from inside

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I am using a random number in a switch case. So have something like:

```
public void something {
Random myRand = new Random();
int number = myRand.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
switch(number)
case 1:
     Do something and on completion go back and start running the something method again.
break:
case 1;
     Do something and on completion go back and start running the something method again.
break;
```

Each case statement could be run through any number of times depending on input from user, some may not even be used.

What I would like is something inside the case statement saying :-

```
public void something (run);
```

Is what I am trying to do possible or is there a better way?

Comment: no, you need to declare your method outside of that method, and call it within your case block.

Comment: Shouldn't the case be followed with a ":" instead of a ";"?

Comment: your use of the word `something` is confusing, "Do something and on completion go back and start running the something method" but this is already IN the `something` method ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Well, @whocares?

Answer (score 0):

You can use do-while statement in this case with a condition to stop the execution.
Call your something method inside do while.

```
do {
something();
} while(condition);
```

This will call your method execute your switch case and again call your something method.

Answer (score 0):

The following code repeatedly calls the runSomeMethod() method for a random number of times.

Use a for loop:

```
public void something() {
    Random myrand = new Random();
    int number = myrand.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
    for(int i=0 ; i<number ; i++) {

        runSomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may i suggest you using interfaces?
what you are trying to implement is known as [functional programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functional-programming-paradigm/) in which you pass functions as an argument to another functions

java supports functional programming in a way by using interfaces and has many built-in interfaces to ease-up the process

i recommend you to take a look at java.util.function package

now lets get on to your code

```
public void something(Supplier<Void> function) {
    boolean condition = true; //use this boolean to control your loop
    while (condition) {
        Random myrand = new Random();
        int number = myrand.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                function.get();
                break;
            case 2:
                function.get();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and you can call your "something" like this

```
public void Call() {

    //if you want to declare the function only once
    something(new Supplier<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void get() {
            System.out.println("the job is done!");
            return null;
        }
    });

    // if you already have a class implementing supplier
    something(new MyFunction());
}
```

not that the Supplier interface is used because your function didn't have any inputs
you can also use Consumer, BiConsumer, Function, BiFunction .... for functions with inputs

Answer (score -1):

concerned about your *CASE* syntax used

Solution goes as follows --> keep looping in a while loop

```
public void something {
    boolean condition = true; // toggle this condition boolean to FALSE, when you want to break the loop
    while(condition){
        Random myrand = new Random();
        int number = myrand.nextInt(10 - 1) + 1;
        switch(number)
        case 1;
             Do something and on completion go back and start running the something method again.
        break;
        case 1;
             Do something and on completion go back and start running the something method again.
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good observation but irrelevant as an answer to the question. You should have it as a comment to OP.